# How can we exclude given directory and sub-directories from getting listed using the find command

Tags: terminal, find, command

Here is my directory structure:

```
/dir_a
     -- /dir_1
        ---/file_11
     -- /dir_2
        ---/file_21
        ---/file_22
     -- /dir_3
        ---/file_31
        ---/file_32
```

I want to print the output in the file as -

```
/dir_a/dir_1/file_11
/dir_a/dir_2
/dir_a/dir_3/file_31
/dir_a/dir_3/file_31
```

I tried with the fine command:

```
find /dir_a/ -not -path /dir_a/dir_2/* >output.txt
```

I don't want **/dir_a/dir_2** in the output.

What could be the way?

Comment: But first you said _I want to print the output in the file as_ and `/dir_a/dir_2` *is* there and then you said _I don't want /dir_a/dir_2 in the output._

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I don't want to print /dir_a/dir_2.

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me -

```
find /dir_a/ | grep -v -e '/dir_a/dir_2/*' >output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find dir_a/* -not -path "*dir_2"
```

(Notice the asterisk in front of `dir_2`)

Output:

```
dir_a/dir_1
dir_a/dir_1/file_11
dir_a/dir_3
dir_a/dir_3/file_31
```

Comment: I don't want to print - /dir_a/dir_2. What you suggest would work, but it will exclude all the dir_2 wherever in the hierarchy.